# Are blocks in Ruby overused?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm starting to learn Ruby and probably unsuprisingly the hardest thing to wrap my head around is blocks.

Looking at some examples of their use some of them just seem unecessary complicated, and almost like someone is trying to obfuscate the code.

For example, here's some migration code from Rails:

```
create_table :posts do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.string :title
    t.text :content
    t.timestamps
end
```

Assuming that the **t** refers to the created table isn't this just the same thing as this?: (added parentheses to make it more clear)

```
t = create_table(:posts)
t.string(:name)
t.string(:title)
t.text(:content)
t.timestamps()
```

How is the first version 'better' or more clear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flip your question: how is the first version more complicated?

Short answer: in general, no. Blocks serve specific purposes.

IMO the block is more communicative because:

- Everything in the block is related
- Scope is enforced at the language level (no more `t` after the block)

Blocks can also execute code before or after the method's `yield`. For example, a block that yields a file can close the file.

Those added parentheses do not make anything more clear: one of the beauties of Ruby (and similar languages) is that optional parentheses make things seem more declarative, which a table definition is.

Comment: With more clear I simply meant that for someone coming from another language the parantheses indicate that a function is being called. The first time I saw the block example I understood what it did - created a table with 3 columns and some timestamps, but now how. It's probably not a problem once you get more used to Ruby.

Comment: @rnd Well, you're asking a Ruby question, so I assumed Ruby conventions.

Comment: @md: "It's probably not a problem once you get more used to Ruby." Very much this. If you try to write Haskell as if you were writing C, you will end up majorly confused. Ruby is Ruby, not PHP, not anything else; it doesn't need dumbing down just to get converts.

Answer (score 5):

One reason to use blocks is if there are things you need to do after the block.

For instance, assume that some private migration method called `now_commit_sql` needs to be called to actually commit the SQL to create your `posts` table. In the second way you listed, it be up to the user to remember to type in `t.now_commit_sql()` (in addition to the `now_commit_sql` method having to be made public).

In the block way, after the `yield`, it can just be called on its own, and thus be more seamless and less error prone for the user. In addition, if the Rails developers needed to call some other method in a future version, such as `log_sql()` or what have you, they could stick it in there instead of the user having to now know to call `t.log_sql()` in addition to `.now_commit_sql()`.

Comment: So, that would be a case where a block is a good idea.  I believe the OP was asking about the other cases, where there doesn't seem to be a benefit to using a block, yet they are still used (such as the example given).

Comment: I guess my overall point is that you may not ever see this specific benefit. Any code you call that uses a block might call some other methods/do some other work after the yield, and that may be why Rails/Ruby uses them a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a block it is clear at first sight that the whole stuff is related. In the second example you have to look twice.

Comment: People have been getting by just fine using the second example in Ruby and many other programming languages for a long time.  I really don't think it's difficult to read at all (and I don't have to "look twice")

Comment: I haven't said you should not use it. But it definitely takes more time to identify the relation if you don't have a block (and use no indentation) - in this example you have to look for the "t" object in everyline and cannot skip them..

Comment: @EdS. The non-block also over-exposes `t` unnecessarily. Even if the cognitive load of the non-block example is only slightly higher, it *is* higher, because there's less separation between the act of creation, and the operations on what has been created. That it's instinctually grokked doesn't *eliminate* it, it *reduces* it. By reducing it even further, blocks help, even if in small ways.

Comment: @EdS. Yep, just like you can ignore anything and pretend it's all the same :)

Comment: @EdS.: People have been getting by just fine for thousands of years with stone axes. Now we have all these newfangled computers... Stone axes were simpler to understand. >.<

Comment: @Amadan: That is a ridiculous comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The real benefit to blocks is that they allow you to pass code as a parameter. You give the actions you want executed to the method, and at some point that method executes your block. When that happens, what happens before and after are encapsulated from you, you just need to be concerned with the code you give to the method.

Is there a situation that could be done another way? Maybe, but the class that you bass the block to changes, you don't need to worry about it or take extra actions, because they are encapsulated and you just have to be concerned with the block code.